# openapi generated client throws away request error information

Tags: javascript, typescript, openapi, openapi-generator

I'm using the [OpenAPI Generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/) and looking at the code generated for my swagger definitions with ["typescript-fetch"](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/typescript-fetch) as my chosen generator I see something weird:

```js
// Code generated to issue requests
protected async request(context: RequestOpts, initOverrides?: RequestInit | InitOverrideFunction): Promise<Response> {
    const { url, init } = await this.createFetchParams(context, initOverrides);
    const response = await this.fetchApi(url, init);
    if (response && (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300)) {
        return response;
    }
    throw new ResponseError(response, 'Response returned an error code');
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Error creation
}
```

now take a look at how the response error is defined:

```js
export class ResponseError extends Error {
    override name: "ResponseError" = "ResponseError";
    constructor(public response: Response, msg?: string) {
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

i.e. the `reponse` itself is passed as a constructor argument and then discarded. **I don't know if this is the reason** but ultimately I get non-informative error messages e.g:

```
Error: {"response":{},"name":"ResponseError"}
```

By inspecting my network tab, I see the POST request has the complete required info and everything should be in that response object. But my hands are tied since the response object itself is ultimately not contained in the error.

- Why is that?
- Is this expected behavior or can some generator option fix it?
- Is there anything else to mitigate this? (I tried using the `..Raw`
  API but it's still using the same error handling mechanism)

I might be doing something wrong in the way I'm trying to print out errors from such an api. If so, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ResponseError object contains the RequestStream of any data coming in. This object also contains the support methods for reading the RequestStream, to be able to do so regardless of the input status type,
The are the json(), text(), and binary() methods for data reading,

What you would like to do I believe is,

```
new Client().method().then().catch(error => {
    error.response.json().then(errorBody => {...});
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I print the whole error like `console.log(`${JSON.stringify(error)})` and there's no extra info there. Would doing `error.response.json().then(` have a different effect? is that because of the continuation with `then` ? I'm under the impression that response is always empty due to the generated code

Comment: after pursuing it on my own, I ended up with pretty much the same thing. Only noticed that the answer is correct when I tried to answer my question and the code looked like yours (must admit I didn't understand it at first). There were some syntax errors which I fixed but it pretty much works, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I cannot tell you why it was implemented in that way. However the sourcecode confirms that it is the intentional behaviour and the generator is working as epxected.

The docs at https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/typescript-fetch do not list an option to change this. However the generator operates on mustache-templates, and you can change those yourself.

in `modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/typescript-fetch/runtime.mustache` you find the Template for the `ResponseError` (line 249 in the current master version of the repo) and you can manipulate it to include the data:

```
export class ResponseError extends Error {
    override name: "ResponseError" = "ResponseError";
    constructor(public response: Response, msg?: string) {
        super(msg);
        this.response = response;
    }
    response : Response;
}
```

Comment: Did that and getting a "duplicate" member error. I found this https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#parameter-properties mentioning that the response argument should also create a member because of the `public` keyword. Maybe then it's a continuation problem as described by the other answer?

Comment: YOu're actually correct, I missed the public keyword. The parameter will then actually be saved, so it beim empty in your output simply means it was either an empty object or it has no public properties but only private ones and getter functions. Read the docs, in that case.

Comment: I mean it's not like I didn't read the docs, even read through the generated code - can't find something specifically for this case. Maybe the getter functions are a solution. The problem is I can see in the network tab that the POST request actually returns a response with the "rich" error info. But when printing the error with as `JSON.stringify(error)` then the `response` object is shown as empty - this means there's nothing there that getter methods would return in addition right ?

Comment: JSON.stringify only uses public properties of the object you pass into it. Hence my remark that it may not hae any.